# Update on total field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, aggregate

i've a problem for a table update. follow table structure:

```
Table1
  tableid
  ...
  ... 
  productID_1
  productID_2
  productID_3

Table2
  productID
  Total
```

I've to totalize each product in table2.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as tot, ProductID_1 FROM Table1 GROUP Table1
```

then the `UPDATE table2 SET total =`..??? (how can i do) `WHERE productID_1 =` ....

Hope you can help me.

Thank you

Comment: What database type?  SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options in terms of simplifying the query greatly depend on the product and version you are using. However, a solution that should work in most databases would be:

```
Update Table2
Set Total = (
            Select Count(*)
            From (
                    Select productId_1 As ProductId From Table1
                    Union All Select productId_2 From Table1
                    Union All Select productId_3 From Table1
                    ) As Z
            Where Table2.ProductId = Z.ProductId
            Group By ProductId
            )
```

A big reason this query is cumbersome is that the data in Table1 is not normalized. Instead you should consider a structure for Table1 like:

```
Create Table Table1 (
                    TableId <datatype> not null
                    , ProductId <datatype> not null
                    , Constraint PK_Table1 Primary Key ( TableId, ProductId )
                    )
```

Comment: I'm using MYSQL. About the sql thank you, it is was i'm looking for. 
About the normalization: i know, but it's a database i've inheritance from a customer.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the first results in a temp table/table variable (if the DB you are using supports it).  For instance, in SQL Server, you can do:

```
declare @t table
(
   key int,
   cnt int
)

insert into @t (key, cnt)
select count(*) as tot, ProductID_1 from Table1 ...
```

If ProductID_2 and ProductID_3 are in the same table, you can union the results.

Then, insert into table 2:

```
insert into table2 (productID, Count)
select key, cnt from @t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACE INTO table2
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, ProductID 
FROM Table1 
GROUP Table1.ProductID
```